# Django templates: Access value list from dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

In view.py I am using the below `for` loop to get json data

```
tables = []
column = []
list = []
for row in result:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    schematab = row[0].encode('utf8') + '.' +row[1].encode('utf8')
    d  = schematab
    tables.append(d)
column = []
for row in tables:
    d1 = collections.OrderedDict()
    tabcol = row.split('.')
    query2  = 'call SP_Get_TABCOL_Names('+str(pid)+',"'+str(tabcol[1])+'")'

    cursor.execute(query2)
    result2 = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in result2:
        d2 = collections.OrderedDict()
        d2 = i[5]
        column.append(d2)
    d1[row] = column
    list.append(d1)
    column = []
    .....
    ....
context = RequestContext(request,{'appuser':'admin','result':json.dumps(list)})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context), content_type="text/html")
```

Result of the loop is data in this format

```
[
 {
    "outlet_db.dim_outlet": ["area , ", "area_mask "], 
    "outlet_db.dim_sales": ["sales1 , ", "sales2 "],
    "outlet_db.dim_product": ["produt1", "product2"]
 }
]
```

Now in views.html im using the below loop

```
{% for key,value in result %}
   {{key}}
   {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

This prints only the json keys, but values are empty. I need both keys and values.

Comment: Is that really your code? I don't see how you call `json.dumps()`, which converts `results` to a string, then loop through it in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use the keyword `list` as a variable name. It is a reserved word in Python. Change it to some other name. Second, based on this line of code, you are passing a list into your context. You also need to remove the `json.dumps` method as this will load a stringified version of your list into your context variable.

```
context = RequestContext(request,{'appuser':'admin','result':json.dumps(list)})
```

This means that in your template code, you must iterate over your list first, before you iterate over your dictionary like so. I just added the `<br>` tags for readability.

```
{% for x in result %}
    {% for key,value in x.items %}
        {{key}}<br>
        {{value}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to stick with your current template code, you will have to pass a dictionary but use the `.items` method like so:

```
{% for key,value in result.items %}
    {{key}}<br>
    {{value}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values in Djangos template language using `dictionary.items`

Try the following:

```
{% for key, value in result.items %}
    {{ key }} 
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```